# Magento -layered Navigation wrong Mapping

Tags: magento, layered-navigation

I have put layered navigation for 3 attributes(manufacturer etc) on my website. When I open url -

**domain.com/category.html**

I get a list of available filters on left panel. Few manufacturer appear on left panel even when those manufacturers dont have product mapped to that category.
When I click on a particular manufacturer - I am redirected to
**domain.com/category.html?manufacturer=50**

I see 3-4 products but one of them is not even mapped to that manufacturer.
I tried deleting all index tables, flat tables, did reindexing but of no help.

**Some Troubleshooting I did -**

When I reindex, product attribute mapping is stored in catalog_product_index_eav table. I checked in catalog_entity tables there are only 4 products mapped to manufacturer-id 50. but on reindexing catalog_product_index_eav table has 5 records for manufacturer id - 50 , I dont kno why this 5th record comes everytime on reindexxing but in actual this 5th product has no relation to this manufacturer.

Could some one help me resolve this?

Comment: are all simple products ?

Comment: Yes @Brats , All are simple products.

Comment: I have the same trouble. Did you solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the fifth product is a configurable? If a simple product belongs to the manufacturer, the configurable will be added.

Comment: No, That is not a configurable product.